# Rendering one mustache partial multiple times with different data

Tags: javascript, partial-views, mustache

I have two objects that I want to render side by side. There is never a case where I will want to render more, or less than two. My model is setup like so:

```
{
  obj1: {...},
  obj2: {...}
}
```

Using mustache templates, I want to render each object using the same partial:

```
<div>
  <h1>Object 1</h1>
  {{>objPartial}}
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Object 2</h1>
  {{>objPartial}}
</div>
```

However, mustache doesn't seem to support passing a context to the partial. Doing something like `{{>objPartial obj1}}` seems like it should be supported, but I can't find any documentation on setting a context for a partial.

Is this sort of thing supported? If not, how can I accomplish the same effect without duplicating the partial (`objPartial1` and `objPartial2`)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax I think you are looking for is not `{{>objPartial obj1}}`, but rather it should be

```
{{#obj1}}
{{>objPartial}}
{{/obj1}}
```

The syntax for `{{#}}` isn't only for arrays - for non array objects the object becomes part of the current scope.

I've forked maxbeatty's example and modified it to show this syntax:

```
<script type="template/text" id="partial">
    <ul>
        {{#name}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/name}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="template/text" id="main">
    <div>
        <h1>Stooges</h1>
        {{#object1}}
        {{>objPartial}}
        {{/object1}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Musketeers</h1>
        {{#object2}}
        {{>objPartial}}
        {{/object2}}
    </div>
</script>​

<script type="text/javascript">    
    var partial = $('#partial').html(),
        main = $('#main').html(),
        data = {

            object1: {
                name: ["Curly", "Moe", "Larry"]},
            object2: {
                name: ["Athos", "Porthos", "Aramis", "D'Artagnan"]}

        },
        html = Mustache.to_html(main,data, {
            "objPartial": partial
        });
    document.write(html);
</script>
```

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YW5zF/3/

Comment: Although I've since moved on from this issue, this answer is indeed correct. Thanks Doug Fish!

Answer (score 2):

You could adjust your model to include the `h1` and `div` so you could loop over a list sending different data to `objPartial` each time

```
<script type="template/text" id="partial">
    <ul>
        {{#name}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/name}}
    </ul>
</script>

<script type="template/text" id="main">
    {{#section}}
    <div>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        {{>objPartial}}
    </div>
    {{/section}}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var partial = $('#partial').html(),
    main = $('#main').html(),
    data = {
        section: [
            {
            title: "Object 1",
            name: ["Curly", "Moe", "Larry"]},
        {
            title: "Object 2",
            name: ["Athos", "Porthos", "Aramis", "D'Artagnan"]}
        ]
    },
    html = Mustache.to_html(main,data, {
        "objPartial": partial
    });
document.write(html);
</script>
```

[See it on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxbeatty/kNpEt/)