# Is it possible to send the result of one mustache template to another?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I am working with mustache and atomic design patterns.

I have a component that is called card which looks a little bit like this

```
<div class="card {{ type }}">
    <h2 class="card-title">
        {{ title }}
    </h2>
    <div class="card-content">
        {{{ content }}}
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to use this in other templates and I would like to send the result from a template as `content`. Something like this:

```
{{> molecules-card(title: 'Title', content: {{> my-content-template }} ) }}
```

The closes I got is:

```
{{> molecules-card(title: 'Title', content: '<div>Long and nasty string of html</div>' ) }}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071627/rendering-one-mustache-partial-multiple-times-with-different-data Does this answer help you?

Comment: Nope. What I want is to be able to select the partial I want to render dynamically